# OpenGL/GLSL: Render to cube map?

Tags: opengl, glsl, cubemap

I'm trying to figure out how to render my scene to a cube map. I've been stuck on this for a bit and figured I would ask you guys for some help. I'm new to OpenGL and this is the first time I'm using a FBO.

I currently have a working example of using a cubemap bmp file, and the samplerCube sample type in the fragment shader is attached to GL_TEXTURE1. I'm not changing the shader code at all. I'm just changing the fact that I wont be calling the function that was loading the cubemap bmp file and trying to use the below code to render to a cubemap.

You can see below that I'm also attaching the texture again to GL_TEXTURE1. This is so when I set the uniform:

```
glUniform1i(getUniLoc(myProg, "Cubemap"), 1);
```

it can access it in my fragment shader via `uniform samplerCube Cubemap`.

I'm calling the below function like so:

```
cubeMapTexture = renderToCubeMap(150, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
```

Now, I realize in the draw loop below that I'm not changing the view direction to look down the +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z axis. I really was just wanting to see something working first before implemented that. I figured I should at least see something on my object the way the code is now.

I'm not seeing anything, just straight black. I've made my background white still the object is black. I've removed lighting, and coloring to just sample the cubemap texture and still black.

I'm thinking the problem might be the format types when setting my texture which is GL_RGB8, GL_RGBA but I've also tried:

GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA
GL_RGB, GL_RGB

I thought this would be standard since we are rendering to a texture attached to a framebuffer, but I've seen different examples that use different enum values.

I've also tried binding the cube map texture in every draw call that I'm wanting to use the cube map:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeMapTexture);
```

Also, I'm not creating a depth buffer for the FBO which I saw in most examples, because I'm only wanting the color buffer for my cube map. I actually added one to see if that was the problem and still got the same results. I could of fudged that up when I tried.

Any help that can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
GLuint renderToCubeMap(int size, GLenum InternalFormat, GLenum Format, GLenum Type)
    {

    // color cube map
    GLuint textureObject;
    int face;
    GLenum status;

    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureObject);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureObject);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    for (face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + face, 0, InternalFormat, size, size, 0, Format, Type, NULL);
    }

    // framebuffer object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, textureObject, 0);

    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    printf("%d\"\n", status);
        printf("%d\n", GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

    glViewport(0,0,size, size);

    for (face = 1; face < 6; face++) {

        drawSpheres();
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + face, textureObject, 0);

    }

     //Bind 0, which means render to back buffer, as a result, fb is unbound
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

       return textureObject;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested to see that your `drawSpheres` function actually draws something visible? Does the function actually draw something? What happens if you change `drawSpheres` to just clear the framebuffer?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing two passes. One in the above code, actually 6 calls above. Then I'm calling drawSpheres when rendering to framebuffer 0 and it does show up.

Comment: Also, I've set my background to white. Wouldn't the white color at least show up in the texture?

Comment: Does your code work fine for a normal FBO? The way I understand it, a cube map should just be six textures, and you'd have to render to each separately..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I can't guarantee that this will help you figure out what's going on. You simply haven't posted enough information about what you're doing to track down any particular errors. Though I can correct one thing of yours really quick:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, textureObject, 0);

...

for (face = 1; face < 6; face++) {
    drawSpheres();
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + face, textureObject, 0);
}
```

This will only call `drawSpheres` *five* times. I'm guessing you wanted to call it 6 times.

But I can post a [working answer.](https://ideone.com/VroYK) Note that this code is designed to be run [alongside my tutorial series](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/), so it makes reference to code that isn't present. But this is mainly things like creating meshes and so forth; nothing truly important.

Here are the salient points. The shaders for the main sphere object.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(std140) uniform;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 modelSpaceNormal;

uniform Projection
{
    mat4 cameraToClipMatrix;
};

uniform mat4 modelToCameraMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = cameraToClipMatrix * (modelToCameraMatrix * position);
    modelSpaceNormal = normal;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 modelSpaceNormal;

uniform samplerCube cubeTexture;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = texture(cubeTexture, modelSpaceNormal);
//  outputColor = vec4(normalize(modelSpaceNormal), 1.0);
}
```

The creation of the cubemap texture that will be used as a render target:

```
void CreateCubeTexture()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &g_cubeTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, g_cubeTexture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    std::vector<GLubyte> testData(CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE * CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE * 256, 128);
    std::vector<GLubyte> xData(CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE * CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE * 256, 255);

    for(int loop = 0; loop < 6; ++loop)
    {
        if(loop)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + loop, 0, GL_RGBA8,
                CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE, CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &testData[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + loop, 0, GL_RGBA8,
                CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE, CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &xData[0]);
        }
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
}
```

I actually fill the texture with data (rather than passing NULL to glTexImage2D) as a debugging aid. It ensures that everything was working prior to starting to use the texture as a render target.

Also, notice that I provide a BASE_LEVEL and MAX_LEVEL. I *always* do that with my textures immediately after creation. It's just a good habit, as OpenGL can be picky sometimes about texture completeness and the mipmap pyramid. Rather than remembering the rules, I just set them to the correct values religiously.

Here's the main drawing function:

```
void display()
{
    //Draw the cubemap.
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, g_framebuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, g_depthbuffer);

    for(int loop = 0; loop < 6; ++loop)
        DrawFace(loop);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    //Draw the main scene.
    //The projection matrix is in a uniform buffer.
    ProjectionBlock projData;
    projData.cameraToClipMatrix = glm::perspective(90.0f,
        (g_viewportSize.x / (float)g_viewportSize.y), g_fzNear, g_fzFar);

    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, g_projectionUniformBuffer);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(ProjectionBlock), &projData);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)g_viewportSize.x, (GLsizei)g_viewportSize.y);

    glClearColor(0.75f, 0.75f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutil::MatrixStack modelMatrix;
    modelMatrix.ApplyMatrix(g_viewPole.CalcMatrix());

    if(g_pSphere)
    {
        glutil::PushStack push(modelMatrix);

        glUseProgram(g_progMain.theProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(g_progMain.modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
            glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix.Top()));

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + g_cubeTexUnit);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, g_cubeTexture);

        g_pSphere->Render("lit");

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);

        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This makes reference to `DrawFace`, which draws the given face of the cubemap. That is implemented as follows:

```
void DrawFace(int iFace)
{
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + iFace, g_cubeTexture, 0);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        printf("Status error: %08x\n", status);

    //The projection matrix is in a uniform buffer.
    ProjectionBlock projData;
    projData.cameraToClipMatrix = glm::perspective(90.0f, 1.0f, g_fzNear, g_fzFar);

    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, g_projectionUniformBuffer);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(ProjectionBlock), &projData);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE, (GLsizei)CUBE_TEXTURE_SIZE);

    const glm::vec4 &faceColor = g_faceColors[iFace];
    glClearColor(faceColor.x, faceColor.y, faceColor.z, faceColor.w);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(g_pSphere)
    {
        glutil::MatrixStack modelMatrix;
        modelMatrix.Translate(g_faceSphereLocs[iFace]);

        glUseProgram(g_progUnlit.theProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(g_progUnlit.modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,
            glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix.Top()));

        const glm::vec4 &sphereColor = g_faceSphereColors[iFace];
        glUniform4fv(g_progUnlit.objectColorUnif, 1, glm::value_ptr(sphereColor));

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + g_cubeTexUnit);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, g_cubeTexture);

        g_pSphere->Render("flat");

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
}
```

This function makes reference to a set of global tables that I use to give each face a distinct background color, a distinct sphere color, and to position the sphere (in camera-space) properly for that face.

The salient points for `DrawFace` are these.

As a general rule, unless I have *certain* knowledge that state is set, I set that state. I set the viewport each time I call `DrawFace`. I set the projection matrix each time. Those are superfluous; I could have set them back in `display` before the loop that calls `DrawFace`, just as I do with the current FBO and depth renderbuffer.

But I *also* clear the buffers, which is different for each face (since each face has a different color).